# Can an OSGi JAR once running ask its container to load another OSGi JAR from another location?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

Lets say I loaded my OSGi JAR into Apache Felix, I wrote the OSGi JAR. Can my OSGi JAR ask Apache Felix to load another OSGi JAR from a HTTP URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. See the javadoc of [BundleContext.installBundle()](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#installBundle(java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream)) function. By calling this function of the bundle context of your own bundle, you can install other bundles from any input stream.